# Dictionary map thinks a String is a String Array

Tags: swift, dictionary

```
struct Item2 {
    var itemid: Int
    var category_id: Int
    var category_name: String
    var name: String
}

struct Item{
    var name = String()
    var rows = [Row]()
}

struct Row{
    var size: Int
}

struct Collapsed{
    var category_opened = Bool()
    var category_id = Int()
    var category_name = String()
    var items = [Item]()
}

let menu2 = [
    Item2(itemid: 5, category_id: 0, category_name: "category1", name: "item1"),
    Item2(itemid: 2, category_id: 0, category_name: "category1", name: "item2"),
    Item2(itemid: 3, category_id: 0, category_name: "category1", name: "item3"),
    Item2(itemid: 1, category_id: 1, category_name: "category2", name: "item4"),
    Item2(itemid: 7, category_id: 1, category_name: "category2", name: "item5"),
    Item2(itemid: 9, category_id: 1, category_name: "category2", name: "item6")]

let mapping = Dictionary(grouping: menu2, by: { $0.category_id })
// Map that dictionary into an array of Sorted and then sort that array by category_id
let collapsedItems: [Collapsed] = mapping.map {
    Collapsed(
        category_opened: false,
        category_id: $0.key,
        category_name: $0.value.map { $0.category_name }, // Error: Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'String'
        items: $0.value.map { $0.name }
    )
}
.sorted { $0.category_id < $1.category_id }
```

I'm trying to re-structure my data with a dictionary, but the 5th line from the bottom gives the error as:

> **Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'String'**

As far as I can tell, `Collapsed.category_name` and `Item2.category_name` are both Strings, so what is the problem?

Comment: Why have you mapped it? Why not just do `category_name: $0.value.category_name`

Comment: @RakeshaShastri `$0.value` is array so you need to access the first object from it, so it should be like  `category_name:  $0.value.first?.category_name ?? ""`

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I forgot to add my Item struct to make it clear. I'm mapping it because I want to collapse my flat item structure in a structure that has items sorted under each category_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty clear.

> Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'String'

This line of code `$0.value.map { $0.category_name }` will return `[String]` you are setting it with a property `category_name` which is type of `String`, on basis of your data that you have added in *menu2* array what you need to set is category_name of first object from the grouping dictionary, because both `category_id` and `category_name` belongs to each other.

**So instead of**

```
category_name: $0.value.map { $0.category_name },
```

**You need to have**

```
category_name:  $0.value.first?.category_name ?? "", 
// You can force wrap the first property too as of you have make dictionary using grouping it will at least have single object.
```

Once you solved this you will get error on line `items: $0.value.map { $0.name }`

> Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type '[Item]'

**So instead of**

```
items: $0.value.map { $0.name }
```

**You need to have**

```
items: $0.value.map { Item(name: $0.name, rows: []) }
```

Comment: I forgot to add my Item struct, that wasn't a typo. I added it now. But after applying your suggestion I'm getting a similar error on the next line: Cannot convert value of type 'String' to closure result type 'Item'

Comment: @Gimmethe411 what is row ? with `Item` struct ?, you need to set it default empty array ?

Comment: @Gimmethe411 Also the error must be `Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to closure result type '[Item]'`

Comment: I added that now, yes just a default empty array.

Comment: @Gimmethe411 Please check the edited answer and set items like `items: $0.value.map { Item(name: $0.name, rows: []) }`